# EasyPHP suitable for development environment?

Tags: php, facebook, easyphp

I'm trying to start php development for facebook applications. I have already had some problems configuring PHP and Apache.

Today I found a tool called [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/). Is it recommended to use this tool for developing php websites and in particular facebook applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EasyPHP is a perfectly good solution as far as I'm aware, but I've never used it myself so I couldn't recommend it. I use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), but it's all down to personal preference.

It's probably worth taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580342/windows-xampp-vs-wampserver-vs-easyphp-vs-alternative) on SO, or [this Wiki article comparing WAMPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs).

Answer (score 2):

[xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)

> XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MySQL, PHP
>   and Perl. XAMPP is really very easy to install and to use - just
>   download, extract and start.

Comment: This is an answer to using EasyPHP for development?

Comment: @Jared would you rather the answer just said 'No'?

Comment: What's wrong with it? I've only heard of EasyPHP, so is it not suitable for web development?

Answer (score 1):

wamp for windows, mamp for mac, thats what I reccommend.

Comment: Is there something about EasyPHP that makes it a poor choice (this is what the question concerns)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual-AMP, It's like the IIS.

Comment: Visual-AMP for Windows, Green portable, requires no installation. Stop related services that are running the program, you can move the directory.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP, MySQL and pretty much any IDE.
Just follow the online instructions.
WAMP includes all the tools and extensions you'll need without needing to mess around with config files