# Unable to load assets when testing website localy

Tags: html, file, debugging, local

I have tested website on my server where everything works fine, its a simple html/css/js based website without any backend functionality, usually I am able to test these without any problems by simply opening pages in browser, however I encountered an issue where this time it only loads up html and it seems that no resources are loaded like js files or css files, the error I get in console is similar to this (in chrome):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

**Edit:** I was able to fix it in chrome by removing '/' in front of file paths, however when testing in ie issue is still present, is there a work around for this?

Comment: Can you please share the code which generates this behavior? It would be easy to find out the solution.

Comment: Are you running the file on your localhost or did you just open the file using Chrome?

Comment: @PrerakSola It is all code associated to linking to external assets like css so for example <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/styles/css/styles.css" />

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Opening index.html in chrome

Comment: @Ilya you have to run your site on your localhost. Your localhost is a local server on your computer. Kind of like the server you run you website on. Just opening it as a file will not allow some functionality to happen, such as ajax requests. What are you going to use for backend? PHP, Node?

Comment: Have  you verified the folder structure on your machine with that on the server?

Comment: @Ilya post some code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problems you are having may be related to how you are opening your web pages in the browser.

You cannot just open them as files: `c:\website\index.html`

Instead, you should install a stack such as WAMP, or XAMPP, or EasyPHP. I recommend [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

After installation, you just type in the browser address bar:

```
localhost
```

And you will see the rendered contents of `index.html` from the `c:\xampp\htdocs` folder.  That folder (c:\xampp\htdocs) becomes your website, and it works exactly like a website. Resources will load correctly.

After installation, just clear out that folder, and copy all your web site .html and .php etc files into that folder. Use the same folder structure you have on your website. A CPANEL website's `public_html` folder is the `c:\xampp\htdocs` folder on your C: drive.

If you create a folder in there, such as dev, and put a file inside it called `mytest.html`, then in the browser address bar you can type:

```
localhost/dev/mytest.html
```

Another great trick is to give yourself a domain by editing the Windows `hosts` file. For example, you can use the `ilya.com` domain locally by editing this file:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Note that the file does not have an extension.

Then, inside that file, at the very very bottom, on a line of its own, type:

```
127.0.0.1     ilya.com
```

After saving that file, when you type in the browser address bar:

```
http://ilya.com
```

You will get the index.html file from your `c:\xampp\htdocs` folder. And if you type:

```
http://ilya.com/dev
```

You will get the index.html file from your `c:\xampp\htdocs\dev` folder.

It is very important to NOT FORGET about that file! It will forever prevent you from accessing the online `http://ilya.com` website. Of course, disabling it is as simple as commenting out that line (by putting a `#` in front) or by messing up the redirect, which is what I usually do:

```
127.0.0.1     xilya.com
```

(Deleting the leading x is easier than retyping the entire line). Coolest thing: the changes take place instantly, without rebooting -- or even bouncing the browser.

Resources:

[Windows: XAMPP vs WampServer vs EasyPHP vs alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580342/windows-xampp-vs-wampserver-vs-easyphp-vs-alternative)

---

One other consideration that I should mention -- and it may not apply to you right now, but perhaps one day in the future -- is to try to match your online hosting account's version of PHP to the version of XAMPP (or WAMP/MAMP/LAMP/EasyPHP) that you install locally.

For example, as of this writing my hosting account serves PHP ver 5.3.29 -- but the current version of XAMPP is on PHP 5.5.19 or 5.6.3. Waaaaay to advanced. The last thing I want to do is program my site, upload it and have to debug the versionitis.

Older versions can be downloaded from the `More Downloads` link, which redirects to here:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/
```

To know what version of PHP your hosting account serves, just create a file on your site, such as: `public_html/somefile.php`.  The contents just need to be these two lines:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

When you browse to that file: `http://mydomain/somefile.php` you will see a page full of PHP config info, with the PHP version prominently displayed at top, in bold. Of course, you can do the same on localhost (that is, in the `c:\xampp\htdocs` folder).