# get text of div and change it through user input

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div box and it has some text in it. How can I change the text through user input ? I want that when a user click on the div box the input field should show up and then user can input some text and it should be updated.

```
<div class="update-card-body">
<p>I want to change this text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var displayBox = document.querySelector('.update-card-body>p');
var input = document.querySelector('.get-text');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  displayBox.textContent = input.value;  
});
```

```html
<input class="get-text">
<div class="update-card-body">
<p>I want to change this text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use the `input` event instead of `keyup` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use HTML5's contenteditable attribute.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable=true][id]').forEach(function(el){
  cardBodyData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('card-body-data'));
  el.addEventListener('input', function(){
   cardBodyData[el.id] = this.innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem('card-body-data',JSON.stringify(cardBodyData));
  });
  if(cardBodyData && cardBodyData[el.id]) {
   el.innerHTML = cardBodyData[el.id];
  }
  if(cardBodyData === null) cardBodyData = {};
});
```

```html
<div id="001" class="update-card-body" contenteditable="true">
  <p>I want to change this text.</p>
</div>
<div id="002" class="update-card-body" contenteditable="true">
  <p>I want to change this text.</p>
</div>
```

SO prevents the use of `localStorage` in the snippet editor.  Here's a fiddle using `localStorage` to save changes to the contenteditable div: https://jsfiddle.net/0rqhmmg3/

Comment: @MahimParsai How permanent do you want it to be?  You could use local storage to retain the changes, but it won't remain if the person clears their cache and local data.  What exactly is the application for having the user change the content?

Comment: @MahimParsai Here's a blog that uses contenteditable and localstorage: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_of_contenteditable_and_localstorage_create_a_web_sticky_note?lang=en

Comment: @MahimParsai I've updated my answer to have a `localStorage` demo on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key part of your question is here: `and it should be updated`

I suspect you mean that you want the text typed by the user to be saved somehow.

You have two options: front-end (`localstorage`) and back-end (`PHP or ASP.Net`)

For localstorage, the code to save looks like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("cardbody", "This is what they typed");
```

and to retrieve it:

```
$('.update-card-body').text(localStorage.getItem("cardbody"));
```

For PHP, you can either use a `<form>` or use AJAX:

References:

[localstorage info](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

[PHP Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

[Info about AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025289/prevent-page-load-on-jquery-form-submit-with-none-display-button#36025530)

---

Note: PHP is very common - it comes with most shared hosting packages (GoDaddy, Hostgator, Namecheap, etc). If you wish to play with it on your local computer, install a free package called XAMPP - it has OSX, Windows and Linux distros. *Note that files go into `xampp/htdocs`, and you view the website by typing ONLY `localhost` into the browser address bar.*

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676358/unable-to-load-assets-when-testing-website-localy/28676901#28676901